# Having a path to an .exe how can I find out if it is running?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I wonder If and how it is possible to find out if say Calc.exe from `C:\Windows\System32` is running or not (on XP and above, not using external applications like `WMIC` ) (something like what `System.Diagnostics` with its  `Process.GetProcesses()` [gives for C# developers](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/get-a-list-of-running-processes-in-c/) but for native `winapi` )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to enumerate the processes and search for a match.

The APIs to use are [`Process32First` and `Process32Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684887%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). [Sample code here](http://www.installsetupconfig.com/win32programming/processstatushelperapis10_5.html).

Comment: This the correct answer, but [you can make it better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) by including a short summary of the relevant portions of the linked sample code. This will also help your answer remain great even if the link you included breaks in the future.

Comment: @Cody thanks, yeah. I'm on a Mac and couldn't find anything on Google; I figured I'd post this to give a pointer in the right direction and come back and add a small code sample if no one else has posted a solution when I'm on my Windows dev PC.